# normal distribution - area under the curve

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The area (in percentage) under standard normal distribution curve of random variable Z within limits from -3 to 3 is ____.

Please provide some hints on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the probability density for z-values between -3 and +3.In the attached snapshots you can see that the P(0<*z*<3)=0.4987. Since the standard normal distribution is symmetrical, P(-3<*z*<0)=0.4987 also. Your question is the probability density in between z-values -3 and +3. In other words, P(-3<*z*<+3), which is the sum of the two densities I highlighted earlier i.e. P(-3<*z*<+3)=P(-3<*z*<0)+P(0<*z*<3)=0.9974

[Density table pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y637u.png)

[Density table pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNT87.png)

Comment: Sorry about my earlier response.

Comment: One more thing. In a standard normal distribution, almost all the density - that is 99% something - is contained within z-values -3 and +3. So 99% is a rough estimate of the probability for z-values in between -3 and +3

Comment: Thanks for those pics got it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the area satisfying $z\le a$ is $\Phi(a)$, where $\Phi$ is the $N(0,\,1)$ cdf. So what's the area satisfying $a\le z\le b$?

Comment: Okay. I got the concept, but how to solve a≤z≤b this part. do I have to use integration from -3 to 3 to f(x) where f(x) is 1/sqrt(2*pi)*e^(-x^2/2).

Comment: @swapnil That's the integral you need. You'll probably obtain it from a resource that can compute $\Phi$. Can you express the value you want in terms of two values of $\Phi$?

Comment: As you mentioned a resource, I saw one graph of standard deviation it took values from -3 to 3 having percentage = 2.14+13.59+34.13+34.13+13.59+2.14 =  99.72

Comment: but I don't know in exam whether they will provide something like this, so is there any other way of doing it. i.e. calculating graph under the curve from 0 to 3 then I will just double it to get required answer.

Comment: @swapril You should research what's provided in your exam, but you'll likely receive a table of values of $\Phi(z)$ for positive values of $z$, which is enough because of the identity $\Phi(-z)=1-\Phi(z)$. The case $a=-b$ gives $\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)=2\Phi(b)-1$.

Comment: Yes, I did research they don't provide us. after more analysis I saw usually they ask values between -3 to 3 so I have to remember those values between 0,1,2 and 3 intervals.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$A={1\over \sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-3}^3 e^{-x^2\over 2}dx$$which can only be calculated numerically using Q-function as follows $$A=Q(-3)-Q(3)=1-2Q(3)\approx 99.74\%$$

Comment: Thank you I will learn more about Q functions.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!